# How to create new object from columns of dataframe in list in R and use this for modeling in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plot, modeling

I have a list of 10 dataframes, called "datalist", on which I want to apply several functions. I am quite new to R. I searched on the internet but can't find the right solution.

The dataframes all have the same variables, like simplified example below:

```
ID FID WETLAND TPI200 TPI350 TPI500 ...
1  1   no wetl 52     35     20     ...
2  2   wetl    21     19     19     ...
...
```

The goal is to execute a PLS-DA model with this data for each dataframe. Therefore I want to first create for each dataframe an X-axis consisting of the values of the variables from the 4th till 8th column and a Y-axis consisting of the 3th column (`"WETLAND"`).
But how do I do this for every dataframe? Is it with `for loops` I can create an X1, X2, ... and Y1, Y2, ... axis for the 10 dataframes? Or should I use `lapply`?

Second, I want to create a PLS-DA model for every dataframes using the created X and Y-axis of every dataframe. I can do this with the following code for one dataframe, but how do I apply this for every dataframe of the list?

```
library(mixOmics)

model.splsda<-splsda(X,Y,keepX = c(5,5)) 
model.splsda$loadings
```

Comment: Something like `lapply(yourlist, function(DF) splsda(as.matrix(DF[, 4:8]), DF$WETLAND, keepX = c(5,5))$loadings)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom model fitting function to subset the data.frames selecting just the columns of interest and run the modeling function.
`lapply` the custom function to the data list and select the loadings from this output list with a `*apply` loop.

```
library(mixOmics)

custom_splsda <- function(data, ncomp, keepX, ..., Xcols, Ycol){
  Y <- data[[Ycol]]
  X <- data[Xcols]
  res <- splsda(X, Y, ncomp = ncomp, keepX = keepX, ...)
  res
}

model_list <- lapply(datalist, custom_splsda, ncomp = 2, keepX = c(5, 5), Xcols = 4:8, Ycol = "WETLAND")
loadings_list <- lapply(model_list, '[[', 'loadings')

loadings_list[[1]]
#$X
#         comp 1     comp 2
#1401 -0.7929405 -0.2459434
#1141 -0.3835902 -0.2429583
#563   0.2417486  0.1065414
#1257  0.3608328 -0.8967159
#509  -0.1883114 -0.2550150
#
#$Y
#       comp 1     comp 2
#AF  0.7071068 -0.7071068
#BE -0.7071068  0.7071068
```

**Data**

The data is from the first example in `help('splsda')`, repeated in order to create a list with several data sets.

```
## First example
data(breast.tumors)
X <- breast.tumors$gene.exp
# Y will be transformed as a factor in the function,
# but we set it as a factor to set up the colors.
Y <- as.factor(breast.tumors$sample$treatment)

names(X) <- breast.tumors$genes$name
df1 <- data.frame(WETLAND = Y)
df1 <- cbind(df1, X)
datalist <- list(df1, df1, df1)
names(datalist) <- sprintf("data_%d", 1:3)
```